# How to add Jquery Mobile navbar within a div (part of page) not at the bottom of page?

Tags: jquery, dom, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am working on App Builder web application. In my page center there is a DIV which like a mobile screen on which I drag and drop different Jquery Mobile widgets and sorting these widgets to built my app. But the problem is when I add NAVBAR (data-role="navbar") the HTML DOM goes inside the target div but it appear at the bottom of my web page. See the screenshots. As there any way to show it within the div (no ifram).

[image]

Comment: IF you are able to provide code then it will be good for us to find solution for you..

Answer (score 0):

This `navbar` must be inside footer div & below `<h4>` tag. DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Rdfxs/16/

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Page content goes here</p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        <div data-role="navbar" data-grid="c">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Sigma Mobility platform http://sigmamobility.com 
where you can create mobile apps using jQuery components through easy drag and drop feature and real-time preview for stacked components.

For your question, you need to put the navbar inside the footer; this would be bring it to the bottom. Other option is to set inline css3 for the navbar for :

```
#navbarid:{
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
}
```

This would move the navbar to the bottom, but it's not recommended as upper controls might overlap the navbar if they close it.